# Applet won't calculate

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, applet, awt

I have an applet program here that allows the user to choose a movie then a number of tickets from a drop-down list. A check box should display for users to click so they can receive a discount for matinee movies. The user should be able to click a calculate price button to display the total cost and a clear button to clear each drop-down list and the check box. The program compiled but when I clicked the calculate button, it generated so many error codes like java.lang.nullPointerException and a lot more. I just wanted the program to work properly so please help me. Please refer to the code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Proj4exe2 extends Applet implements ItemListener, ActionListener
{
Choice movieChoice = new Choice();
Button calcButton = new Button("CALCULATE");
Choice ticketsChoice = new Choice();
Button clearButton = new Button("CLEAR");
Checkbox matineeBox = new Checkbox("Matinee Discount", false);
Label outputLabel = new Label("");
int i = 1;
int size;
double presyoKo[];
double totalPresyo = 0.00;
double diskwento;

public void init()
{
setBackground(Color.yellow);
add(new Label("Welcome to ENCORE MOVIES"));
add(new Label("Please choose a movie:"));
add(movieChoice);
movieChoice.addItem("My Little Bossings");
movieChoice.addItem("Pagpag");
movieChoice.addItem("San Pedro Calungsod");
movieChoice.addItem("Kimi Dora Prequel");
movieChoice.addItem("10,000 Hours");
    movieChoice.addItem("Girl, Boy, Bakla, Tomboy");
    movieChoice.addItem("Boy Golden");
    movieChoice.addItem("Kaleidoscope World");
movieChoice.addItemListener(this);
add(calcButton);
calcButton.addActionListener(this);
add(ticketsChoice);
ticketsChoice.addItem("0");
ticketsChoice.addItem("1");
ticketsChoice.addItem("2");
ticketsChoice.addItem("3");
ticketsChoice.addItem("4");
ticketsChoice.addItem("5");
ticketsChoice.addItem("6");
ticketsChoice.addItem("7");
ticketsChoice.addItem("8");
ticketsChoice.addItem("9");
ticketsChoice.addItem("10");
ticketsChoice.addItem("11");
ticketsChoice.addItem("12");
ticketsChoice.addItem("13");
ticketsChoice.addItem("14");
ticketsChoice.addItem("15");
ticketsChoice.addItemListener(this);
add(clearButton);
clearButton.addActionListener(this);
add(matineeBox);
matineeBox.addItemListener(this);
add(outputLabel);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String args = e.getActionCommand();
    if(args == "CALCULATE")
    {

        size = i++;
        presyoKo[i] = Double.parseDouble(ticketsChoice.getSelectedItem());

        totalPresyo = presyoKo[i] * 50.0;
        outputLabel.setText("Your charge is " + totalPresyo + ". Thank you.");
        }
        if(args == "CLEAR")
        {
            movieChoice.select(0);
            ticketsChoice.select(0);
            matineeBox.setState(false);
            outputLabel.setText("");
            }
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ee)
    {
        diskwento = (totalPresyo * .25);
        if(matineeBox.getState() == true)
        {
            totalPresyo = totalPresyo - diskwento;
            }
        }
}
```

The applet code:

```
<html>
<applet code = "Proj4exe2.java" height = "450" width = "450">
</applet code>
</html>
```

Pardon me for the clumsy design because I didn't create a layout manager. I very much welcome tips and comments to further improve the code for this program. Thank you so much!

Comment: Debug my friend! No one can tell you fix for NPE unless u point out line number

Comment: One problem is this .. `args == "CALCULATE"`.. Change it to `args.equals("CALCULATE")`.

Comment: Use the getActonCommand() method of the button.This is easier done through Java NetBeans or other Java IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double presyoKo[];` is used in actionPerformed before it is initialized

**EDIT**

Instead of using an array use an ArrayList and keep adding to it

```
ArrayList<Double> ticketPrices = new ArrayList<Double>();
...
... actionPerformed(...) ...
  double qty = Double.parseDouble(ticketsChoice.getSelectedItem());
  ticketPrices.add(qty * 50);
```

Comment: So should I place double presyoKo[] within actionPerformed?

Comment: This results in error "variable presyoKo[] might not have been initialized" when I placed it within actionPerformed just before String args.